# Extend LVM partition with the parent drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, lvm

I want the `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` partition to use the whole `sda3` disk. So the `/` would be 296.1GB.
Any idea how can i do that? Cause i dont know how to do this way.
I have 0 idea what am i doing, i accidentally installed lvm with ubuntu server and here iam.

```
server@serverlaptop:~$ df -H
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               786M     0  786M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              167M  1.7M  165M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  106G   19G   82G  19% /
tmpfs                              832M  758k  831M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              832M     0  832M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          2.1G  111M  1.9G   6% /boot
tmpfs                              167M     0  167M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                              167M     0  167M   0% /run/user/996

server@serverlaptop:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 296.1G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

server@serverlaptop:~$ sudo fdisk -lu
sudo: unable to resolve host serverlaptop: No address associated with hostname
Disk /dev/sda: 298.9 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HTS54323
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 25440A85-BBF0-4358-B190-ED83430C7363

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   4198399   4194304     2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  4198400 625139711 620941312 296.1G Linux filesystem




Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Follow this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337406/just-200-gb-of-my-1tb-disk-can-be-found-on-ubuntu-server-20-04?rq=1

Comment: Thank you! It is solved!

Comment: Yes, Thank you!